# Adjusting intensity on an image

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, image

I am trying to increase the intensity of a grayscale image while maintaining the outline of the image.The algorithm I'm creating only looks at values in the left, right, upper and lower neighbors of each cell, effectively only processing the interior cells of the array. Obviously there are lines and lines of code but I am being thrown the `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` on this one block (I can provide it all if needed). Can someone tell me what my problem is or offer advice on what needs a second look?

```
public Image getEdgeImage(){
    Image edge = new Image(this);
    for(int row = 1; row < numRows; row++) {

        for(int col = 1 ; col < numColumns; col++) {

        double Lx = -.5 * edge.pixels[row -1][col].getRed() + (.5 * edge.pixels[row + 1][col].getRed()) ;
        double Ly = -.5 * edge.pixels[row][col -1].getRed() + (.5 * edge.pixels[row][col + 1].getRed());

        int L = (int) Math.sqrt((Lx * Lx) + (Ly * Ly));
        edge.pixels[row][col] = new Color(L, L, L);
        }
    }
    return edge;
}
```

Comment: your getting `ArrayOutOfBoundException`?

Comment: @AbinMDevasia yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your getting `ArrayOutOfBoundException`, Please do watch on the area your accessing the Array element by `+/-` the index.

In your program the line No 5 & 6, your accusing the next elements with out checking the array length.

```
 edge.pixels[row + 1]
 edge.pixels[row][col + 1]
```

[image]

Array Index will start from `0` to `length-1`, Suppose your array has the length of `10`, and on the `9th` iteration your program will check for the index `10` in line 5&6 the code highlighted above.